# Adreno420 on QHD underperforms than Adreno330 and Adreno320 on FHD?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es-3.0

I made an image processing application using OpenGL ES 3.0.
The size of the image is 830X640. 
So I use glViewport to perform GPU processing only on 830X640 region.
Fallowing is the part of my code.

```
glViewport(0, 0, 830, 640);
glUseProgram(mProgram);
glBindVertexArray(mVBState);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture_EE_output);
glUniform1i(h_sampler5, 0);

GLsync syncFence5 = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, 1);
glDeleteSync(syncFence5);
```

And I measured FPS of my app on Galaxy S5 (Adreno 420, ***QHD***), Nexus 7 (Adreno 320, FHD) and Nexus 5 (Adreno 330, FHD).

The result was Adreno 330 (59 Hz) > Adreno 320 (45Hz) > Adreno 420 (35 HZ).
As I expected Adreno 330 shows an better performance than Adreno 320.
But Adreno 420 shows underperformance than Adreno 330 and andreno 420.

So I'm suspecting the resolution of displays influence to FPS.
On the other hands, I already used glViewport to avoid this happens.

Am I wrong to use glViewport to partially rendered?
Or are there other problems that I've never noticed?

Thank you for reading.